# How to add OPENXML as prerequiiste along with the setup created using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, installation, openxml

I need to install OpenXML before installing my software in clients PC, as i am using openxml references to read excel data.

Please let me know how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Basically the heart of the Open XML SDK is the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` library, so all you need to do is to distribute this dll with your software.

Comment: Oh..is it so... I will try.